# How can I have shared views inside an Area in ASP.NET MVC 2.0?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-areas

Can I have a Shared Views directory inside a Area where I can put partial views/user controls to be shared amongst the controllers of that specific Area?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a a `Views/Shared/` folder inside each area (or if there is not, you can create one - `Areas/%AreaName%/Views/Shared`).  This works in the same way as the main `Views/Shared/` folder, but just for that area.

Comment: Are you sure about that?